# Allocating an array of strings

Tags: c

I'm trying to create an array to store multiple strings in. The maximum size of the string is 100.

This is what my struct looks like:

```
typedef struct
{
  int size;

  int capacity;

  char** elements;

} array_strings;
```

I allocate space for an empty array in the following function:

```
array_strings *array_strings_new()
{
    array_strings *vec;

    vec = (array_strings *)malloc(sizeof(array_strings));
    if (vec == NULL)
        return NULL;

    vec->size = 0;
    vec->capacity = 0;
    vec->elements = NULL;

    return vec;
}
```

And then I try to insert elements in the end of the vector with the following function:

```
int array_strings_insert(array_strings *vec, char *string, int pos)
{
    int i;

    if (vec == NULL || pos < -1 || pos > vec->size)
        return -1;

    /* increases capacity if needed */
    if (vec->size == vec->capacity)
    {
        if (vec->capacity == 0)
            vec->capacity = 1;
        else
            vec->capacity *= 2;


vec->elements = (char **)realloc(vec->elements, vec->capacity *sizeof(char *));
        for (int i = 0; i < vec->capacity; i++)
        {
            vec->elements[i] = realloc(vec->elements[i], 100*sizeof(char));
        }
        if (vec->elementos == NULL)
            return -1;
    }

    /* if pos=-1 inserts at the end of the array */
    if (pos == -1)
        pos = vec->size;

    /* Copy elements from pos to pos+1 until the end of the array */
    for (i = vec->size - 1; i >= pos; i--)
    {
        strcpy(vec->elements[i + 1], vec->elements[i]);
    }

    /* copy string */
    strcpy(vec->elements[pos], string);

    vec->size++;

    return pos;
}
```

When I try to insert a a string I get "realloc(): invalid pointer
Aborted (core dumped)".

Can someone tell me what Im doing wrong?

Thank you,

---

I tried doing this:

```
vec->elements = (char **)realloc(vec->elements, vec->capacity *sizeof(char *));
        for (int i = 0; i < vec->capacity; i++)
        {
            vec->elements[i] = NULL; 
            vec->elements[i] = realloc(vec->elements[i], 100*sizeof(char));
        }
        if (vec->elementos == NULL)
            return -1;
    }
```

And I no longer get "realloc(): invalid pointer Aborted (core dumped)". However the first elements of the array are empty for some reason.

Comment: `vec->elements[i]` is not null after `realloc`. You can't `realloc` it right after allocating it.

Comment: How should I allocate each vec->elements[i] then?

Comment: You cannot call for `realloc` before calling for `alloc` first.

Comment: You allocate them ok. You should set `vec->elements[i] = NULL` before calling `realloc(vec->elements[i], ...`. So you need to save old capacity. Then realloc. Then initialize all the elements between old capacity and new capacity to NULL. Then you can call realloc on the newly allocated pointers.

Comment: @KamilCuk I tried doing what you suggested and commented bellow. Am I doing it right?

Comment: @AlexLop, where should I malloc If I dont know the number of strings I willl be needing?

Comment: Yes and no. You are leaking memory on the second time you enter the function. If `vec->elements` already hold some pointers, `vec->elements[i] = NULL` will leak memory.

Comment: @MiguelL Actually you can initialize the pointer to NULL and then call for `realloc`, in such case it will act as the regular `malloc`.

Comment: I believe that is the problem I am having now.  Where should I Initialize each vec->elements[i] to NULL without leaking memory? @KamilCuk

Comment: I tried to do that bellow, howerver the first elements of the array are being erased. @AlexLop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The realloc code you wrote will destroy the strings stored previously. e.g. in case of data size increase from 2 to 4, the first 2 strings will be lost.

You can modify the realloc portion as follows.

```
int prevcapacity;
if (vec->size == vec->capacity)
{
    prevcapacity = vec->capacity;    
    if (vec->capacity == 0)
        vec->capacity = 1;
    else
        vec->capacity *= 2;

    vec->elements = (char **)realloc(vec->elements, vec->capacity *sizeof(char *));
    for (int i = prevcapacity; i < vec->capacity; i++)
    {
        vec->elements[i] = malloc(vec->elements[i], 100*sizeof(char));
    }
}
```

In this case, you can use `malloc` on the extra strings allocated. The previous strings will be preserved.